# Should I be using the little copper bit inside this 3/8 water connection?

Tags: plumbing, water

The adapter I use to get standard 3/8” water connections on the 1/2” pex in my home (to replace a faucet for example) always comes with a little copper piece (on the right of the picture) inside the connection.

[image: 3/8” Connection and Brass Piece]

What is this? Should I be using it? I sort of assumed that it and the nut there are for if you're running your own custom line, but now I’m getting paranoid that I’m messing up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an olive for use with a copper pipe.

The pex fittings I use have a split collar as they are designed with the water seal internally onto the brass spigot and the nut/collar is to secure the pipe into place.